# What does invariant exactly mean and how does it get the invariant?

Tags: numerical-methods, wave-equation, invariant-theory

I have read many journal about simulation of regularized long wave. In numerical test section,many researcher use invariant of mass,momentum and energy to check accuracy of their method but i found there are different kind of the invariant that they've used.here example of invariant of energy.
$$
I_3=\int_{a}^{b}u^3+3u^2\ dx
$$
i get this equation from " Solitary Wave Solutions for the Regularized Long-Wave Equation " by D.Irk
and this is another example.
$$
I_3=\int_{a}^{b}u^4-3\mu u_x^2\ dx
$$
this equation is taken from " A Numerical Solution of The Modified Regularized
Long Wave (MRLW) Equation using Quartic B-Splines " by S. Battal Gazi Karakoc et al.
so, how does it get the equations?

Comment: Please ask a specific question, providing appropriate definitions and references.

Comment: thank you for your answer and comments about my question. i will edit my question.